# How do I create a CActiveRecord with attributes not present in the table?

Tags: php, yii, user-registration, yii-cactiverecord

I have an Active Record Model for Users in my application, and I was hoping to re-use this model for the user registration form. The user registration form has a few fields which I don't want to store in the database, such as the password and password confirmation (I'm storing a salt and a hash instead). Is there a way to do this with my existing User Active Record Model, or should I create a separate Form Model for the User registration form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare the variables in your model and then add rules for them using the scenario attribute as @Dan mentioned.

You model would look something like:

```
class User extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $password_confirm;
    public $password_hash;
    ...
```

and your rule in the model would look like:

```
array('password, password_confirm', 'required', 'on'=>'register')
```

and you also might want to use the CCompareValidator rule or similar to check the password fields match. See [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model#declaring-validation-rules).

Comment: Any idea how to loop this new attributes mixed with original ones?
Using foreach only returns table attributes :S

Comment: @ldg, How to get all of the attributes, var_dump($model->attributes);exit; retruns only the table attributes. Not the static one. How to get all of the attributes in controller?